# Count of Distinct Rows Without Using Subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, distinct

Say I have Table1 which has duplicate rows (forget the fact that it has no primary key...)  Is it possible to rewrite the following without using a JOIN, subquery or CTE and also without having to spell out the columns in something like a GROUP BY?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1
) T1
```

Comment: Why don't you want a subquery?

Comment: @erikkallen: more of a ponderance, really.  I like knowing my options :)

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(col1)) FROM T1`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT ProductName) FROM Products
```

but if you want a count of completely distinct records then you will have to use one of the other options you mentioned.

If you wanted to do something like you suggested in the question, then that would imply you have duplicate records in your table.

If you didn't have duplicate records `SELECT DISTINCT * from table`  would be the same without the distinct.

Comment: Thanks for that example - this was my exact problem when I came searching.

Comment: OP said "SELECT *", but I just need a distinct count of a PK where a one-to-many join blows up the row count. So, "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PK_ID)" was exactly the syntax I needed.

Comment: @JohnChase glad my 11 year old answer was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 9):

No, it's not possible.

If you are limited by your framework/query tool/whatever, can't use a subquery, and can't spell out each column name in the GROUP BY, you are SOL.

If you are not limited by your framework/query tool/whatever, there's no reason *not* to use a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

if you really really want to do that you can just "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY all,columns,here" and take the size of the result set as your count.

But it would be dailywtf worthy code ;)

Comment: Yeah, thus the "I don't want to use a GROUP BY" statement in my question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to refine the answer by saying that you need to check that the datatype of the columns is comparable - otherwise you will get an error trying to make them DISTINCT:

e.g.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

This is true for large binary, xml columns and others depending on your RDBMS - rtm. The solution for SQLServer for example is to cast it from an ntext to an nvarchar(MAX) from SQLServer 2005 onwards.

If you stick to the PK columns then you should be OK (I haven't verified this myself but I'd have thought logically that PK columns would have to be comparable)